# Filenames garbled and truncated when accessed through cifs mount

Tags: mount, cifs, encoding, filename

I have multiple machines all running Ubuntu 20.04, accessing a shared drive in the form of a Synology NAS. There appears to be a bug in the way character encoding is treated by one of the machines.

Files written to the NAS by machine A will have invalid characters inserted in place of special characters like ":" when read from machines B and C, and when those files are modified by machines B or C, machine A will now see the filename as something like "KXEP9K~U.LOG" instead of the original name.

The inconsistencies in naming do not appear when files are accessed via other means, such as USB sticks or synology sync folders. Only when accessed through the mounted directories. This leads me to believe that it is an issue with character encoding during mount.

All systems have identical output from 'locale'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apologies, 20.04

Comment: I still have not found a *solution* to this bug, but I have found a workaround in disabling the synology sync and directly mounting the server volumes on all machines. This creates network lag for remote sites, but resolves the encoding bug which seems to be baked into synology.